# Limit the list of views in a Document library in WSS 3.0

Tags: sharepoint, wss

Is there a way in WSS 3.0, Windows Server 2003 to restrict in a document library the list of Views a given user or group is allowed to select/use?

We have defined document libraries and Views that show only the documents a user or group is allowed to see. The problem we have is that any user could select a View that is meant for a different group.

And upgrading to MOSS Enterprise is not an option for now.

Answer (score 1):

In your question you say you have views that "show only the documents a user or group is allowed to see."  And the problem is other users can see these views, and therefore see documents they should not.  It sounds like the bigger issue you have is using views for security.

There are any number of ways a user can see a document that isn't presented to them in a view.  If your intention is to prevent users from seeing certain documents your best options are to use separate document libraries and set permissions accordingly (which inherently gets around your view problem) or put your documents in folders and set item level security on the folders.

As far as your question, I think the answer is no, you cannot prevent a user with permission to a document library from seeing its public views.  If a user has permission to a library they have permission to the views as well.

If you're really not worried about security you could always create a custom page to view documents through, and on that page limit the views that are presented in the UI.  How you'd approach that depends on your skill set and what tools you have.  These types of solutions are messy though, since it relies on your users going through your custom interface, and there are many ways SharePoint will take your users to the OOB pages instead.